# Is it possible to use rust macro to build items of a tuple?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
fn foo<T> { println!("foo: {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>()); }
let functions = (foo::<i32>,build_fn!(i64,u64,f32,f64;foo),foo::<u32>);

// the final `functions` is 
let functions = (foo::<i32>, foo::<i64>, foo::<u64>, foo::<f32>, foo::<f64> ,foo::<u32>);

// maybe more complex like build_fn!(i64,u64,f32,f64;foo,boo)
```

Is it possible to write `build_fn` macro ?

------------- edit line --------------

In my case, I was doing something with bevy. I managed to get something like this. Which is little ackward solution, but still working thanks to the flexibility of bevy ecs.

```rust
macro_rules! unit_team_system {
    ($($team:ty),* ; $sys:tt) => {
        ($(unit_team_system!(@make_fun $team; $sys),)*)
    };
    (@make_fun $team:ty; ($($sys:ident),* $(,)?) ) =>{
        ($($sys::<$team>,)*)
    };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TeamA;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TeamB;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TeamC;

fn system_a<T>() {
    println!("system_a: {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>());
}

fn system_b<T>() {
    println!("system_b: {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>());
}

fn main() {
    let systems = unit_team_system!(TeamA, TeamB, TeamC;
               (
                system_a,
                system_b,
                )
        );

    systems.1.0();
}
```

----------------- proc_macro -----------------
Still not posssible to generate subitems of a tuple.

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{Ident, Token, Type};
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream};


struct UnitTeamSystem {
    teams: Vec<Type>,
    systems: Vec<Ident>,
}

impl Parse for UnitTeamSystem {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let mut teams = Vec::new();
        let mut systems = Vec::new();
        while !input.is_empty() {
            if input.peek(Token![;]) {
                break;
            }
            if input.peek(Token![,]) {
                input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
            }
            let team: Type = input.parse()?;
            teams.push(team);
        }

        input.parse::<Token![;]>()?;

        while !input.is_empty() {
            let system: Ident = input.parse()?;
            systems.push(system);
            if input.peek(Token![,]) {
                input.parse::<Token![,]>()?;
            }
        }
        Ok(UnitTeamSystem {
            teams,
            systems,
        })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn unit_team_system(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let UnitTeamSystem { teams, systems } = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as UnitTeamSystem);

    let mut tokens = Vec::with_capacity(teams.len());

    for team in teams {
        for system in &systems {
            tokens.push(quote! {
                #system::<#team>,
            });
        }
    }

    eprintln!("{:?}", tokens);

    TokenStream::from(quote! {
        (#(#tokens)*)
    })
}
```

Comment: In your example the macro could also just generate the whole tuple (which is possible). Is that true for your real use case too?

Comment: yes, I compromised to the whole tuple workaround. But my real case is more complex, I need combination of two group of types and functions. Due to the same repetition limit of rust macro, seems impossible to make the result in single tuple, but in tuple tuple structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to write `build_fn` macro ?

Not with declarative macros, because a declarative macro has to generate *an entire language item* (statement, expression, type, pattern, ...).

Here you're trying to generate a section of tuple, which is not an item of the rust language.

It might be possible using a procedural macro, because IIRC procedural macros operate in terms of token streams, so while they are generally used to generate items, they *might* be able to generate sub-items or partial items (I've never actually used them that way).

Comment: I've tried use procedural macro. It is also impossible, the output token stream need to be a valide language item. Fix me, if I'm wrong